# Hibernate doesn't save entity, only if I double save

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, vaadin

I'm developing an application using Vaadin and I am having some trouble:
When I try to save and object with Hibernate, nothing appears in my table unless i double save it.

Code from my class:

```
if (referenciacao==null){
    referenciacao = (Referenciacao)referenciacaoSession.newEntity();
}
referenciacao.setMedico((Medico)cbbMedico.getValue());
referenciacao.setOrigem((Origem)cbbOrigem.getValue());
referenciacao.setReferenciacaotipo((ReferenciacaoTipo)cbbReferenciacaoTipo.getValue());
referenciacao=referenciacaoSession.saveAndFlush(referenciacao);
```

My `Referenciacao` Entity:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 *
 * @author pepatusco
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "referenciacao")
public class Referenciacao extends BaseBean implements Serializable {

    public static final String PROPERTY_ID = "id";
    public static final String PROPERTY_MEDICO = "medico";
    public static final String PROPERTY_ORIGEM = "origem";
    public static final String PROPERTY_REFTIPO = "referenciacaoTipo";

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "medico_id")
    private Medico medico;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "origem_id")
    private Origem origem;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "referenciacao_tipo_id")
    private ReferenciacaoTipo referenciacaoTipo;

    public Medico getMedico() {
        return medico;
    }

    public void setMedico(Medico medico) {
        this.medico = medico;
    }

    public Origem getOrigem() {
        return origem;
    }

    public void setOrigem(Origem origem) {
        this.origem = origem;
    }

    public ReferenciacaoTipo getReferenciacaotipo() {
        return referenciacaoTipo;
    }

    public void setReferenciacaotipo(ReferenciacaoTipo referenciacaoTipo) {
        this.referenciacaoTipo = referenciacaoTipo;
    }


    public Referenciacao() {
         //this.id = null;
    }

}
```

My `Referenciacao` DAO:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import pt.app.dpn.base.common.beans.entity.Medico;
import pt.app.dpn.base.common.beans.entity.Origem;
import pt.app.dpn.base.common.beans.entity.Referenciacao;
import pt.app.dpn.base.common.beans.entity.ReferenciacaoTipo;

/**
 *
 * @author pepatusco
 */
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface ReferenciacaoRepository extends JpaRepository<Referenciacao, Long> {

    List<Referenciacao> findByMedico(Medico medico);
    List<Referenciacao> findByOrigem(Origem origem);
    List<Referenciacao> findByReferenciacaoTipo(ReferenciacaoTipo referenciacaoTipo);
    Referenciacao findByMedicoAndOrigemAndReferenciacaoTipo(Medico medico, Origem origem, ReferenciacaoTipo referenciacaoTipo);
    Referenciacao findById(Long id);

}
```

My `ReferenciacaoSession`:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Local;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Default;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import pt.app.dpn.base.common.beans.dao.ReferenciacaoRepository;
import pt.app.dpn.base.common.beans.entity.BaseBean;
import pt.app.dpn.base.common.beans.entity.Medico;
import pt.app.dpn.base.common.beans.entity.Origem;
import pt.app.dpn.base.common.beans.entity.Referenciacao;
import pt.app.dpn.base.common.beans.entity.ReferenciacaoTipo;

/**
 *
 * @author pepatusco
 * 
 */
@Default
@Stateless
@Local(ReferenciacaoSessionLocal.class)
public class ReferenciacaoSession implements ReferenciacaoSessionLocal, Serializable {

    @Inject
    private ReferenciacaoRepository referenciacaoRepository;

    @Override
    public void flush() {
        referenciacaoRepository.flush();
    }
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public <S extends Referenciacao> S saveAndFlush(S s) {
        return referenciacaoRepository.saveAndFlush(s);
    }


    @Override
    public Long getCount() {
       return referenciacaoRepository.count();
    }

    @Override
    public List<BaseBean> findAll() {
        List<BaseBean> listBaseBean = new ArrayList<>();
        referenciacaoRepository.findAll().forEach((referenciacao) -> {
            listBaseBean.add(referenciacao);
        });
        return listBaseBean;
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void save(Object o) {
        referenciacaoRepository.save((Referenciacao)o);
        referenciacaoRepository.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(Object o) {
        referenciacaoRepository.delete((Referenciacao)o);
    }

    @Override
    public Object newEntity() {
        return new Referenciacao();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Referenciacao> findByMedico(Medico medico) {
        return referenciacaoRepository.findByMedico(medico);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Referenciacao> findByOrigem(Origem origem) {
        return referenciacaoRepository.findByOrigem(origem);
    }

    @Override
    public Referenciacao findById(Long id) {
       return referenciacaoRepository.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Referenciacao> findByReferenciacaoTipo(ReferenciacaoTipo referenciacaoTipo) {
       return referenciacaoRepository.findByReferenciacaoTipo(referenciacaoTipo);
    }

    @Override
    public Referenciacao findByMedicoAndOrigemAndReferenciacaoTipo(Medico medico, Origem origem, ReferenciacaoTipo referenciacaoTipo) {
        return referenciacaoRepository.findByMedicoAndOrigemAndReferenciacaoTipo(medico, origem, referenciacaoTipo);
    }

}
```

Can anyone tell me why, when I do save, nothing appears in the table but when I do save again it saves a `Referenciacao` in the table?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the reason for this behavior, so let me at least try to help to debug this thing.

I see multiple possible things that might be going on:

1. The repository for your entity doesn't get called on the first try, for some reason outside of the code you showed us.
2. The repository does not store your entity.
3. Something goes haywire with your transactions, causing you not to see the changes (I'm actually betting on this one).

In order to rule out (1) put a breakpoint or a logging statement next to the `referenciacaoRepository.save` and `referenciacaoRepository.saveAndFlush` statements to ensure, that code path gets executed.

In order to rule out (2) activate SQL logging, to see if SQL statements actually get executed as expected. Obviously, you *should* see insert statements getting executed.

To tackle the third one, activate transaction logging to see when transactions start and end. There should be a transaction getting started before the save and getting commited afterward. Verify that this actually happens and that there are no other transactions running.

Let us know if you were able to solve your problem.

Side note: Why do you have `ReferenciacaoSession`? It really doesn't do anything and seems to be perfectly replaceable by the repository.

Comment: Thanks @JensSchauder but I had to do my class all over again and the problem disappeared... now I'm having the same problem in a differrent class but I´m trying to debug it.